# Android Snoop Sniff Protection - needed?

Tags: android, security

I have a simple IM/chat program. The Android client sends username and message to my server via HTTP (along with a JSessionID to track the session). I want to avoid a malicious user posting as another user..

Do I need to worry about someone sitting near by user in a cafe, and snooping out their JSessionID and posting as my user? Or, snooping out the username+password that I send to the server when I first contact the server and initially get my JSessionID?

How much is snooping / sniffing an issue and how can I protect against it if it is?

Answer (score 1):

On publickly accessible WLAN  - yes, definitely.  On 3G network - maybe.  It is possible, but pretty expensive and generally not available to skript kiddies.

Since you can not be sure, whether user uses WLAN or 3G  you shall take precautions. There are good practices:
  - use https
  - do not store user credentials on device (use 0auth instead)

Be as paranoid as necessary

Comment: @You can sniff 3g with off the shelf hardware and a special rainbow table.  I saw it at defcon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a serous vulnerability [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) and its trivial to prevent.  Just make sure the jsessionid is always transmitted over https.